# Django rest update one field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I just got started with Django and got stuck on something that I believe should be simple, but I don't know how to do.

I have a model like this one:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=true)
...
amount = models.IntegerField()
...
```

Basically, the user will give an amount and the model needs to be updated with the current amount + the amount that the user inputs.

I use serializers to create new objects, but I don't really know how to use them to do this.

Comment: Maybe a good starting point is this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41110742/719247

Comment: try to use `patch` instead of `put`

Comment: @PaoloStefan I saw that post, but that would not have in mind the current value stored in the model, which is something I need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's assume the following:

1. your model is called `MyModel`
2. your serializer class is named `MyModelSerializer`
3. `AmountPartialUpdateView` is extending `APIView`
4. your partial update url is defined like this -that is, model id is
   passed in the `pk` URL variable and the amount to add is passed in the `amount` URL variable:

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       # ...
       url(r'^model/update-partial/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<amount>\d+)$', AmountPartialUpdateView.as_view(), name='amount_partial_update'),
       # ...
   )
   ```

Then, you should implement the correct update logic in the `AmountPartialUpdateView.patch()` method. One way to accomplish this is:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import Response


class AmountPartialUpdateView(APIView):

    def patch(self, request, pk, amount):
        # if no model exists by this PK, raise a 404 error
        model = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
        # this is the only field we want to update
        data = {"amount": model.amount + int(amount)}
        serializer = MyModelSerializer(model, data=data, partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        # return a meaningful error response
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This way, visiting the URL

```
model/update-partial/123/5
```

you will increase the `amount` of model id **123** by **5** units.

Comment: How should be the URL I need to send the request to: whatever/model/update-partial/pk=1&amount=10 ? I am getting an 404 error on every combination I tried, and I know there is an object with that pk

Comment: Right, it does something now. I get an error unsupported operand types for +: int and str. Both model.amount and amount are int, so I don't get why is it complaining about that.

Comment: No, it's right: the `amount` in the URL segment is passed as a stirng to the patch() function - upated the answer again.

Comment: OK, now I just need to create the update method in the serializer then. Let me try.

Comment: `def update(self, instance, validated_data):
instance.amount = validated_data['amount']
instance.save()
return instance`

Shouldn't this work? I am getting an error simply saying KeyError amount

Comment: It's not mandatory: if your MyModelSerializer extends rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer, then my code will suffice without needing to override the serializer's update() method.

Comment: Yep, that made the trick. Thank you so much! You are a life saver!

Answer (score 4):

just use the  partial=True as one of your serializer parameter and create an object for your filed that you want to update i.e i want to update the queue status

```
    data = {'queue_status': 1}
serializer_patient_queue = PatientQueueSaveSerializer(queue_item, data=data, partial=True)
```